# How do I stage changes interactively like `git add --patch`?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I stage changes interactively like `git add --patch` from within VSCode?

Answer (score 2):

- view the file from the SCM bar ==> gives a diff view
- on the right side (modified file) select part of the file you want to stage
- Right-Click and select **Stage Selected Ranges**
- you can do this multiple times